# Can the critical buckling load from non-linear FE calculation be higher than the one from linear?

Tags: finite-element-method, buckling

Let's consider a FE buckling calculation without plasticity.

Is there theoretically any chance that the non-linear analysis will give a higher buckling load than the linear one?

Comment: The linear and nonlinear analyses will be different because the mathematical formulation is different. So the critical loads will be different. Unless you tell us *exactly* what you did (which might mean providing the complete input data files), there is no way to guess whether "different" means "higher" or "lower".

Comment: To be more specific i'm talking about a buckling of a cylinder. The acting load is vacuum.

Comment: Your Linear analysis should be to a degree diferent, and likely lower than your nonlinear, as it's only valid around a specific point. It can be depending on the model and maths, wildly incorrect compared to the nonlinear one.